# Given a random variable, how to find its distribution?

Tags: statistics

for example, let $U$ be uniform distribution $(0,1)$. Let $X=(-1/ \lambda) logU$. Show it has a exponential distribution.

This is from my test question, and I'm not sure if I remember it correctly.

I try to use moment generation function. somehow I remember a theorem states that two random variable, if the moment generations function equals in some neighbor containing $0$, they have same distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt on probability distributions, I find it clearest to work with cumulative distribution functions.  In the case of your problem, you have
$$F(u) = P(U \leq u) = u$$
and then 
$$P(-\frac{1}{\lambda} \log U \leq x) = P(\log U \geq -x\lambda) = P(U > e^{-x\lambda}) = 1-e^{-x\lambda}
$$
Now that you have the c.d.f. $P(X \leq x) = 1-e^{-x\lambda}$ the derivative gives the proability distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

General strategy is to find its CDF:
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X < x\} = \mathbb{P}\{U > e^{-\lambda x}\} = \begin{cases} 0 &\textrm{ if } x < 0 \\ 1 - e^{-\lambda x} &\textrm{ if } x \ge 0\end{cases}
$$
This is CDF of the exponential distribution